# Display Post image on the Custom Page Template with Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I have this code for my page template.

This is what i have right now: http://www.ohright.com/emoticons/

How do I change it so that it can display all my post images at 20 images per-page and with a pagination below?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: emoticons-page
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div id="main">
<?php query_posts('cat=44'.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p><?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You can use `'posts_per_page' => 20`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: emoticons-page
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $posts_per_page = 20;
        query_posts('cat=44&post_status=publish&paged=' . $paged . '&posts_per_page=' . $posts_per_page);?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; 
        posts_nav_link();
        wp_reset_query();
        endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: As a alternative you can use this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/